# "select * into" is too slow

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, spring-batch

i have a stored procedure in sql server:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.basic_json_normalization_full 
    @tableNamep sysname,
    @tableName sysname,
    @columns_list NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @json_query NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @rows_count INT OUTPUT AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;
    
    DECLARE @main_tableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'dbo.' + @tableName;
    DECLARE @raw_tableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'dbo.' + 'raw' + @tableNamep;

    -- Truncate the main table  DECLARE @truncateQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @truncateQuery = 'TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.' + @tableName;
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @truncateQuery;

    -- Construct the dynamic SQL
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = N'
    BEGIN TRAN;
    INSERT INTO ' + @main_tableName + '
      (_id, ORIGINAL_ID, ' + @columns_list + ')
    SELECT j.[_id], j.[ORIGINAL_ID], ' + @columns_list + '
    FROM ' + @raw_tableName + ' r
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(r.raw_data)
      WITH ( _id nvarchar(155) ''$._id'', ORIGINAL_ID NVARCHAR(150) ''$.ORIGINAL_ID'', ' + @json_query + ') AS j;
    SET @rows_count = @@ROWCOUNT;
    COMMIT TRAN;
    ';

    -- Execute the dynamic SQL
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@rows_count int OUTPUT', @rows_count = @rows_count OUTPUT; END; GO
```

this procedure is consumed in a spring batch tasklet, more specifically in a method called `JsonNormalize` :

```
@Override
    public int jsonNormalize(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, String tableName, String chargement) {
              return simpleJdbcCall.withProcedureName("basic_json_normalization_full")
                    .withSchemaName("dbo")
                    .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("@tableName", Types.NVARCHAR))
                    .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("@tableNamep", Types.NVARCHAR))
                    .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("@columns_list", Types.NVARCHAR))
                    .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("@json_query", Types.NVARCHAR))
                    .execute(in);
}
```

and this is the tasklet snippet code:

```
@Bean
    public Step BasicNormalization(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder(String.join("", BASIC_NORMALIZATION), jobRepository)
                .tasklet(basicNormalizationTasklet(), transactionManager)
                .throttleLimit(5)
                .build();
    }
```

is there any way to make this one faster a bit, because, till now, it takes 4 hours to treat 1.2M rows.

**PS:** I tried executing this in SQL Server Management Studio and it takes too long too, so is there any way to use the multi-threading or partitionning option in spring batch to make it faster .

Comment: Have you tried to execute the stored procedure outside the spring batch job? I believe this important to do as a first test to make sure the performance hit (if any) is coming from spring batch or other factors (like a missing index in the database, etc).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine yes, i tried it and it is slow too but i though maybe if i use the multi-threading option for spring batch, it will resolve the issue

Comment: FYI, that procedure is dangerous and wide open to all sorts of injection attacks. I would fix that before considering any speed improvements.

Comment: is it 1.2 million of rows in the @raw_tableName? which you then json shred into real rows, how many do those generate? if the json is one level only, that's way too slow. i don't think there's much you can do since your stored procedure just does a simple openjson, what kind of hardware are you running

Comment: @ThomA actually we have a great security system so our VMs are not easily accessible and that is why i'm not that worried about the security.

Comment: @siggemannen the json I provide is one level. Actually, the idea is that I have about 1.2M rows in raw_tableName (row_id and row_data which have the json) and I need to normalize this data using the stored procedure. If you have a faster method, you're welcome to suggest it.

Comment: Ahh, so you are saying that if someone set the value of `@tableName` to be `N'MyTable; CREATE LOGIN SSA WITH PASSWORD = ''1'', CHECK_POLICY = OFF; ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER SSA;--'` your server would "magically" know not to run such dangerous code? (Assume `MyTable` is a real table.)

Comment: @ThomA to execute this query successfully, the user running the query would typically need administrative privileges on the SQL Server instance which is hard to get and that's what i'm relying on.

Comment: Is your json very big? OPENJSON shouldn't be beatable by anything else custom made. But i still wonder, it seems too slow to process only those rows. Do you have a lot of foreign keys etc in the target table?

Comment: You're missing the point, @maryemneyli . You are allowing the user to *inject* **ANYTHING**.

Comment: @siggemannen actually yes, the json is quiet big but it is one level. I've tried the bulk insert but it took much more time.

Comment: @maryemneyli, the caller will be your java app, and it will need pretty high permissions just to run this. The procedure executes `truncate table` dynamically and doesn't have `with execute as owner` clause, which means the caller (your app) must have at least `db_ddladmin`. If an attacker will find a way to "convince" your app to pass their string as a parameter, the first one will probably be `select * from sys.objects`. And the next something like `select * from dbo.Users u inner join dbo.Salaries s on s.UserId = u.Id`. See the problem?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-threading won't improve the performance of the step and might even produce incorrect results as multiple threads would be executing the same procedure concurrently on the same data set.

What you can try is partition the input dataset and configure a partitioned step where each worker processes a distinct partition (ie each thread will call the procedure on a different dataset). This way, you would have different workers processing distinct datasets in parallel (not the same dataset concurrently).